# Compare DateTime.Now to exact time

Tags: c#

I want to have exact time of the day on the timer elapsed event 
Below is what I am trying to do

```
    string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm");

        if (now == "1630")
        {
            int a = 10;
        }
```

even when the time is 1630 the if statement is false,What am I doing Wrong here.

Comment: If you declare a local variable and set it to a value like that, I am not surprised if it does nothing meaningful.

Comment: That really *will* go into the `if` statement if it's 1630. As Alvin says, you're not doing anything useful in the body of the `if` statement. I also *wouldn't* compare `DateTime` values by converting them to strings...

Comment: why is converting DateTime to string a bad practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No idea why you convert current time to `string`

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
if (currentTime.Hour == 16 && currentTime.Minute == 30)
{
     int a = 10;
}
```

Comment: Wrong, he wants to compare with `16:30`  ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter not that important. We need to leave some space for the OP to think.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, it's my local time actually :)

Comment: @AndreyGordeev now you know why there is no checkmark at your answer ;DDD

Answer (score 1):

Avoid converting time to string ,Do somrthing like this

```
if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:09:00"))
{
 int a = 10;
}
```

Comment: I will be worried about the seconds component.

Comment: -1 for using `TimeSpan.Parse` when there is absolutely no need to do so

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan dbaseTime = TimeSpan.Parse("16:30:00");
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == dbaseTime )
   a=10;
```

Comment: -1 for using `TimeSpan.Parse` when there is absolutely no need to do so

Comment: Indeed. new TimeSpan(16, 30, 00) is the correct way. (Apart from being slow, TimeSpan.Parse() also suffers from localization problems and requires an IFormatProvider argument to make it safe.)